# VueJS SSR import image

Tags: vue.js, webpack, leaflet, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I made app with vue-cli and @akryum/vue-cli-plugin-ssr (babel and eslint plugin tools).
I try to import image in component - it's working without ssr - but obtain error at load.

> 500 | Internal Server Error

```
/dev/node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { �PNG
                                                              ^

>SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:316:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at r (/dev/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js:9315:16)
    at Object.leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png (webpack:/external "leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png":1:0)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Map.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (js/app.js:815:93)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
    at Module../src/components/Map.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (src/components/Map.vue?d6e9:1:0)
```

in my component I use ES2015 syntax of import :

Map.vue

```
import icon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'
import iconShadow from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png'
// ...
data () {
    return {
        icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: icon,
            shadowUrl: iconShadow
         })
    }
},
// ...
// other use of the object this.icon
```

I have upgrade my webpack config to :
vue.config.js

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    // config.resolve.symlinks(false)
    config.resolve.extensions.add('png')
    config.module.rule('markdown').test(/\.(md)$/).use('file')// .loader('url-loader').loader('file-loader')  
    config.module.rule('image').test(/\.(png|jp?eg)$/).use('file').loader('url-loader').loader('file-loader')
},
pluginOptions: {
    'style-resources-loader': {
        preProcessor: 'scss',
        patterns: []
    },
    ssr: {
        host: '0.0.0.0'
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try removing `.loader('url-loader')`?

Comment: I remove `image` rule and try import with assets/logo.png (from vue). That work